# ExpressionSet with a custom gene list

Tags: r, filtering

After an ExpressionSet is established,
I want it to contain only the genes of my choice ("selected.txt")

What is the best approach??

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to tthe site. Could you show us which format is your selected.txt files? And how is your ExpressionSet object ? In this types of question explaining what do you have and what you have tried make it easier for us to help you.